# Java - throw and catch in same method

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, throw

I have problem with understand existing code. I would like to know how Java manage throw exception and catch it in same method. I can't find it in other question so I preapare example. What will be output of run below code in Java?

```
public static void main(String [ ] args) {
     try{
         System.out.println("1");
         method();
     }
     catch(IOException e) {
         System.out.println("4");
     }
}

public static void method() throws IOException {
     try {
         System.out.println("2");
         throw new IOException();
     }
     catch(IOException e) {
         System.out.println("3");
     }
 }
```

It will be **1** **2** **3** or **1** **2** **4**?

Comment: 1 2 3 will be output

Comment: Can you not try to run it yourself?

Comment: it won't compile unless you declare method as static. Once you fix that, as @findusl says, the output will be 1,2,3

Comment: I agree with @findusl ... `method()` should catch and swallow the exception.  If it rethrew the exception, you'd also get `4` in the output.

Comment: @pruntlar I would like to know how Java manage throw exception and catch it in same method. I can't find it in other question so I made one another.

Comment: @kuba44 that's not what you asked.

Comment: I would consider this bad form.  If you throw it inside the method, bubble it out for others to handle.  Swallowing it inside the method is a sign that you may as well not throw the exception.

Comment: So it won't be **1** **2** **4** ? I thouht that throw exception will be catched on main method. And this is resone why I made this question.

Comment: @pruntlar I edit my question. Now is it good?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, let's check:

```
    public static void main(String [ ] args) {
         try{
             System.out.println("1"); //<--When your code runs it first prints 1
             method();  //<--Then it will call your method here
         }
         catch(IOException e) { //<---Won't catch anything because you caught it already
             System.out.println("4");
         }
    }

public static void method() throws IOException { //<--Your Signature contains a throws IOException (it could throw it or not)
     try {
         System.out.println("2");  //<--It will print 2 and thow an IOException
         throw new IOException(); //<--now it throws it but as you're using a try catch it will catch it in this method
     }
     catch(IOException e) {//the exception is caught here and it so it will print 3
         System.out.println("3"); //<--Prints 3
     }
 }
```

Now, if you remove your `catch` clause in the `method()` method for something like this, now it will catch it for you:

```
    public static void main(String [ ] args) {
         try{
             System.out.println("1"); //<--When your code runs it first prints 1
             method();  //<--Then it will call your method here
         }
         catch(IOException e) { //<---It will catch the Exception and print 4
             System.out.println("4");
         }
    }

public static void method() throws IOException { //<--Your Signature contains a trows IOException (it could trhow it or not)
         System.out.println("2");  //<--It will print 2 and thows an IOException
         throw new IOException(); 
 }
```

Remember, a try-catch means: CATCH IT OR THROW IT (someone else will catch it, and if not it will go to the main and stop your process).

Comment: "Remember a Try catch means : CATCH IT OR TRHOW IT" - ok, I know. But I thought that throw keyword will get run program out of `method()`.

Comment: It would do it if you hadn't had caught the exception in the same method

Answer (score 1):

**1 2 3** will be the output.

not **4** because the exception is caught in the `method`'s try-catch block

Comment: So it won't be **1** **2** **4** ? I thouht that throw exception will be catched on main method.

Comment: In the main method, there is no exception propagated as it was caught in the _method_'s try-catch block. Please, try to experiment with your piece of code then it will be clear to u :)